# 2013 App View List of Host Web with ListViewWebPart

Tags: 2013, xslt-list-view-web-part, app

Is it somehow possible to use the XsltListViewWebPart in the SharePoint-Hosted App to view and manipulate a List of the Hostweb?

```
 <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" ID="full" Title="loc:full">
                            <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server"
                                ListUrl="Lists/Listname" <--- Relative URL! Only AppWeb? Or also HostWeb?
                                IsIncluded="True"
                                JsLink="clientTemplate.js"
                                NoDefaultStyle="TRUE"
                                PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW"
                                Default="False"
                                ViewContentTypeId="0x">
                            </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
                        </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use the above to display the list OTB but i have found it quite limiting. But OTB you can add items, select views (that you've created in VS2012) etc.

I've only done this on lists that the APP creates, does your lists exist in the parent web?

Comment: The question clearly states that the list is in the Host web, not the app web